# Drop down menu not pushing content down but display over top?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have been trying to make the drop down menu push content down rather than display over the other buttons.

I have looked at other solutions and I have tried but I get strange output. I believe it's because I have a system of inline grids for each drop down button.

I tried setting position to relative and absolute, but did not achieve the desired results. I experimented with similar code but with only one inline-grid with 1 column and 2 rows, and it works, but it does not work for me in the main website.

I also tried deleting the absolute position from the .dropdown-content class, but it doesn't respond like it should.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.html .body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
}

.griddy {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: 35px;
  background-color: pink;
}

[class^='ssof'] {
  display: grid;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav {
  border: 2px solid;
  background-color: darkcyan;
}


/* .topnav a {
                float: left;
                display: block;
                color: #f2f2f2;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 14px 16px;
                text-decoration: none;
            } */


/* .body {
                background-image: "nico.png";
                display: grid;
                grid-template-rows: auto, 1fr, auto;
                grid-template-columns: 100%;
            } */

.banner {
  display: flex;
  grid-auto-columns: 80% 20%;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.placeme {
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 20%;
  border: 2;
  height: 36px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  outline: 0;
}

.main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  /*100%*/
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  gap: 20px;
}

.maincontent {
  display: grid;
  /* outline: 3px solid black; */
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 8fr;
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  outline: solid 8px lightgray;
  /*20% 80%*/
  /* grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto; */
}


/* [class^='sidenavinline'] { */

.sidenavinline {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: 60px 60px 60px;
  /* outline: solid 3px black; */
  grid-auto-rows: 60px;
  gap: 10px;
}


/* .one {
                display: grid;
                outline: solid 2px blue;
    
            } */

[class^='one'] {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* outline: 3px dashed #f90; */
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #333;
  gap: 10px;
}

.mainmain {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 150px;
  /* outline: solid blueviolet; */
  /* grid-auto-columns: 1fr; */
  grid-auto-rows: 150px;
  gap: 10px;
}

[class^='submain'] {
  /* display: grid; */
  /* outline: dashed 3px black; */
  background-color: white;
  /* grid-auto-rows: 32%; */
  /* position: absolute; */
}

.footy {
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 30px;
}


/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd
}


/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>


<body>
  <div class="banner"><input type="text" placeholder="Search.." class="placeme"></div>
  <div class="griddy">
    <div class="ssof">home</div>
    <div class="ssof">search</div>
    <div class="ssof">bagicon</div>
    <div class="ssof">account</div>

  </div>

  <div class="topnav">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="sidenav"> p </div>


    <div class="maincontent">
      <div class="sidenavinline">
        <div class="one">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="one">b</div>
        <div class="one">c</div>
        <div class="one">b</div>
        <div class="one">e</div>


      </div>
      <div class="mainmain">
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items</div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>

      </div>
    </div>


    <footer>
      <p class="footy">bottom content</p>
    </footer>

  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `position: absolute;` `.dropdown-content`. That  takes it out of the flow. There's also no need for `z-index: 1;` when it doesn't overlap.

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.html .body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
}

.griddy {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: 35px;
  background-color: pink;
}

[class^='ssof'] {
  display: grid;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav {
  border: 2px solid;
  background-color: darkcyan;
}


/* .topnav a {
                float: left;
                display: block;
                color: #f2f2f2;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 14px 16px;
                text-decoration: none;
            } */


/* .body {
                background-image: "nico.png";
                display: grid;
                grid-template-rows: auto, 1fr, auto;
                grid-template-columns: 100%;
            } */

.banner {
  display: flex;
  grid-auto-columns: 80% 20%;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.placeme {
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 20%;
  border: 2;
  height: 36px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  outline: 0;
}

.main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  /*100%*/
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  gap: 20px;
}

.maincontent {
  display: grid;
  /* outline: 3px solid black; */
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 8fr;
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  outline: solid 8px lightgray;
  /*20% 80%*/
  /* grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto; */
}


/* [class^='sidenavinline'] { */

.sidenavinline {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: 60px 60px 60px;
  /* outline: solid 3px black; */
  grid-auto-rows: 60px;
  gap: 10px;
}


/* .one {
                display: grid;
                outline: solid 2px blue;
    
            } */

[class^='one'] {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* outline: 3px dashed #f90; */
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #333;
  gap: 10px;
}

.mainmain {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 150px;
  /* outline: solid blueviolet; */
  /* grid-auto-columns: 1fr; */
  grid-auto-rows: 150px;
  gap: 10px;
}

[class^='submain'] {
  /* display: grid; */
  /* outline: dashed 3px black; */
  background-color: white;
  /* grid-auto-rows: 32%; */
  /* position: absolute; */
}

.footy {
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 30px;
}


/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  /* position: absolute; */
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  /* z-index: 1; */
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd
}


/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>


<body>
  <div class="banner"><input type="text" placeholder="Search.." class="placeme"></div>
  <div class="griddy">
    <div class="ssof">home</div>
    <div class="ssof">search</div>
    <div class="ssof">bagicon</div>
    <div class="ssof">account</div>

  </div>

  <div class="topnav">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="sidenav"> p </div>


    <div class="maincontent">
      <div class="sidenavinline">
        <div class="one">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="one">b</div>
        <div class="one">c</div>
        <div class="one">b</div>
        <div class="one">e</div>


      </div>
      <div class="mainmain">
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items</div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>
        <div class="submain"> this is where we put items </div>

      </div>
    </div>


    <footer>
      <p class="footy">bottom content</p>
    </footer>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: @Bamar, thank you for the suggestion and I tried both these before but it does not work.  if you increase the screen viewing area then you will understand what i mean. Although it should work, for some reason it does not. I cant figure out why?  in the code sniper you wrote when you run it, it makes couple of the buttons dissapear. its very frustating to say the least. It should technically work but does not? I am confused.